# Execute script after onchange event of input file in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, promise

I want to know if it is possible to execute a script just after the onchange event of an input file finished? If so, how?

I'm very new to promises but I want know if this can be achieved, specifically for the input file

```
<input type="file" id="myInput" multiple />
var inputControl = $('#myInput');
inputControl.on('change', function(e) { //Do something } ); //<--here call a script but only after onchanged finished 
//inputControl.on('change', function(e) { //Do something } ).then(function(){ alert('later'); })?
```

The purpose is to create a collection of files added to the input file and in some different moment to display or do another thing with that collection. I want to separate responsibilities.

**UPDATE**

I reformulate my question, but I don't know if should delete this question and create another or just add it here. I will proceed here, if an admin ask to delete or create another question I will do it.

I went so far and to nowhere with my question above. I want to chain this

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq5go22c/)**

```js
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(event) {     
    alert(event.target.result);
}
.then(completeIntroduction); // <--- Here execute a script after the onload ended

reader.readAsText(new Blob(["hello "]));

function completeIntroduction(){
  alert("world");
}
```

Comment: The change event occurs after customer selected a file/s and filedialog closed. Please expand your idea.

Comment: Yes I know. When the user selects all the files and the dialog closes I just want to create a collection of the files when the onchange raises and then if it is necessary to chain another function to display the files or maybe later. I want to reuse the display of files right after the onchange or an a later stage.

Comment: Promises are probably not the tool you need. You could always dispatch a custom event at the end of the `Do Something` code

Answer (score 1):

This how you can listen on changing the input

```
<input id="myInput" type="file">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var inputControl = $('#myInput');
inputControl.on('change', function(e) {
  alert(this.value);
});
inputControl.on('change', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function(obj)
  {
    alert(obj.value);
  },500, this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am talking specifically for the input of type file. I updated my question. A script right after the onchange event finished.

Comment: OK, i updated the code, this is working but it is not straight forward way , you will give 500 ms to the first code to execute and then start executing the second part, if you can have a callback from the first part it will be better

Comment: setTimeout 0 is enough to ensure any synchronous code within the change event handler is finished

Answer (score 0):

Little idea:

```
           var inputControl = $('#myInput');
            //Store Files in array object.
            var files = [];

            inputControl.bind('change', function (e) {
                files.push($(this));
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    showAllSelectedFiles();
                },1000);
            });

            function showAllSelectedFiles(){
                for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
                    var file = files[i];
                    var name = file.val();
                    //Your code here.
                }
            }
```